# BIND9: Combining key and ACL for allow-update

Tags: linux, bind

I have set up a BIND 9 server and configured cryptographic keys in order to allow updates from a client. Now in my `named.conf`, I have set the following:

```
allow-update { key dns1.example.org.; };
```

This works and I can perform updates (add, delete zone records) from my client (`nsupdate` command).

I am wondering if I can combine it with an ACL. Basically I want that the client needs the correct key, but also must come from a certain subnet or IP address. Can I do this somehow? I failed to find anything about that scenario in the docs.

Comment: Why you need both ? Isn't the key alone enough ?

Answer (score 9):

Alcs are first match.  If you exclude the addresses you want, you can reject all non matching addresses using any; then check that the key matches.

```
   allow-update { !{ !allowed; any; }; key keyname; };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ugly answer #1**

You can do this only if you are willing to be creative, ugly and brute altogether.

To allow updates only from 1.2.3.0/24 having key dns1.example.com.

```
acl “mix-match” {
! 128.0.0.0/1;
! 64.0.0.0/2
! 32.0.0.0/3
! 16.0.0.0/4
! 8.0.0.0/5
! 4.0.0.0/6
! 2.0.0.0/7
! 0.0.0.0/8     //0 instead of 1 since bit is set in the desired network
! 1.128.0.0/9
! 1.64.0.0/10
! 1.32.0.0/11
! 1.16.0.0/12
! 1.8.0.0/13
! 1.4.0.0/14
! 1.0.0.0/15    //0 instead of 2 since bit is set in the desired network
! 1.3.0.0/16    //1-st bit = 1: we DENY hosts with 1.3.0.0/16 but allow 1.2.0.0/16
! 1.2.128.0/17
! 1.2.64.0/18
! 1.2.32.0/19
! 1.2.16.0/20
! 1.2.8.0/21
! 1.2.4.0/22
! 1.2.0.0/23    //0 instead of 2 since bit is set in the desired network
! 1.2.2.0/24    //1-st bit = 9: we DENY hosts with 1.2.2.0/24 but allow 1.2.3.0/24

key dns1.example.com.;
};
```

How to do that bitwise math:

1. For /X subnet you need X rows.
2. Convert subnet IP into binary form.
3. You start with 1-st bit - if allowed subnet have this bit set you deny rule will have it clean, and if the bit is 0 in the allowed subnet then your rule will deny that bit set.
4. For rule #N, N-1 first bits are SAME as in the desired subnet mask, bit N is as described in step 3.

I did not actually try, but should work.

If you have multiple allowed subnets, I wish you a good luck.

For the purpose of this answer, I'm glad IPv6 isn't widely deployed yet. :)

**Ugly answer #2**

Setup separate *stealth* (i.e. not listed as NS) primary master nameserver, in it's firewall rules allow packets only from "allowed" subnet **and** from it's slave nameservers. On this stealth, allow updates with the key alone. Configure slaves to get zone data via AXFR/IXFR and NOTIFY. And don't forget to disable update forwarding on the slaves.

**Once you did it either ugly way**, keep in mind that *anybody* from *anywhere* can spoof source address in that UDP DNS update packet, which makes all those efforts completely pointless. (Though you can disable UDP to make the efforts slightly less pointless).

Answer (score 0):

I know you can define a match_list but I am not sure if you can combine the key and match list.

```
allow-update { address_match_list };
```

for example:

```
options {
    allow-update { !192.168.2.7;192.168.2/24;};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but according to my understanding the definitions are:

```
address_match_list = element ; [ element; ... ]
element = [!] (ip [/prefix] | key key-name | "acl_name" | { address_match_list } )
```

and therefore you can do things like

```
acl “mix-match” {
“two-subnets”;
! 10.10.30.101;
10.10.30.0/24;
key dns1-dns2.example.com;
};
zone "abc.def.example.com" in {
        type master;
        file "named.abc.data";
        allow-update{ mix-match };
};
```

and therefore zones transfers are now restricted to those that have a key (beyond the match list).

Comment: It will allow updates without the key - _first match_ is used.

Comment: I believe @Sandman4 is right. What is not clear (and I have not tried it yet) is if we place the key element first would that imply a valid key for the match that will follow? ie a combination of key and address match.